# Event sourcing: multiple aggregates for event

Tags: event-sourcing

Is it possible that event has two aggregates, for example:  `UserPostCommentAdded` refers to `User` and `UserPost` aggregates? Or I don't understand the aggregate concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that event has two aggregate?

Both yes and no.

Yes, it is common that an event will include references to more than one "aggregate".

```
UserPostCommentAdded: {
    userId: 001ae072-1834-4b73-90af-666ec0edc04a
    userPostId: 6c01a87c-e64f-466a-9f1a-b6af28049248 
}
```

What you *don't* normally see is two different aggregates that use the same event to update their own state.  Which is to say, the relationship of the `UserPost` is the responsibility of the `UserPost`, or it is the responsibility of the `User`, but not *both at the same time*.

> Usualy I see single aggregateId field in implementation, no?

You will sometimes see that; but unless you are doing something very specialized, "aggregate" won't be part of your domain's language, so it really doesn't make sense in your event data.  You might *lift* the identifier of one of your domain entities into the meta data...

```
UserPostCommentAdded: {
    data: {
        userId: 001ae072-1834-4b73-90af-666ec0edc04a
        userPostId: 6c01a87c-e64f-466a-9f1a-b6af28049248
    }
    metadata: {
        aggregateId: 6c01a87c-e64f-466a-9f1a-b6af28049248
    } 
}
```

For instance, you might do something like this if you were using domain agnostic plumbing to route your events around.  *In this sense*, you would probably only have a single aggregateId in the metadata, identifying the aggregate that *wrote* the event in the first place.

Comment: Usualy I see single `aggregateId` field in implementation, no?